Example of complete zero-characteristic normed field $F$ with open balls not homeomorphic to $F$?
For $F$ a normed field (i.e. a normed ring (Definition 2.1 at the link) that is also a field), let us say $F$ has property "$P$" if any open ball in $F$ (with any center and of any positive real radius) is (when given the relative/subspace topology from $F$) homeomorphic to $F$ itself.
I'm wondering about what would be some "minimally restrictive" conditions for a (metrically) complete, zero-characteristic normed field $F$ to have property $P$.
To this end, I was wondering if anyone would have a suggestion as to what would be an example of a complete zero-characteristic normed field that fails to have property $P$?
Does it fail for e.g. the $p$-adic numbers? Would anyone know a hint or a reference that discusses this?
(Please also feel free to share any insights about my question in the above 2nd paragraph, as well.)

If $F$ is locally compact, like $p$-adic fields, this is impossible because open balls of positive ("finite") radius are compact while $F$ is not.

On the other hand, this is true for every countable normed field where one (hence any) open ball is infinite, by the argument in https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2740112/96384 (which also shows all such fields are homeomorphic to each other). This includes e.g. all number fields with any $\mathfrak{p}$-adic metric.

@TorstenSchoeneberg Thank you for your suggestions and insights!
